# React-Redux design pattenrs: Should a "deep" component be wired to Redux, or receive props from parent components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I'm building some instant messaging app using React and Redux in the frontend. I have components like "Main"(initializes the web socket and renders other components), "Chat", "FriendsList" and "Friend"

I often find my self wondering, if i should wire a child or a grandchild to Redux directly(assuming it needs it), or to pass those props from the parent/grandparent.

For example, i render "Chat" in the Main component this way:

```
 <Chat
    onTyping={this.onTyping}
    onSubmitMessage={(value) => { this.submitMessage(value) }}
    messages={this.props.messages[this.props.activeFriend] || []}//This comes from Redux
    isMessagingAvailable={this.isMessagingAvailable()}    
  />
```

As you can see, i'm passing a "messages" prop, which in turn comes from Redux. I could of course just wire Chat to Redux independently.

The question is then, whether there is some convention regarding the best practice in this situation. **Should every component that consumes global state be wired to Redux directly?**

Comment: Your main can import a container component of Chat that uses [redux connect](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) to hook up the state and dispatch methods of Chat.

Comment: So basically you're saying i could wire Chat to redux? I know this, but i'm wondering about the best practice :D Or maybe i didn't really understand what you meant.

Comment: Main is importing Chat but instead of importing Chat it imports a container of Chat.  The container knows what part(s) of the state to select and what dispatch functions you need. Chat is just a dumb component that receives props. I'd say the container of Chat belongs to Main since Main knows where to import it, what state it'll assign to it and how it's actions are implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

The idea behind modular design is to have as many generic component as possible.

These components should be independent of outer world(*i.e. Redux Store*).

In my understanding, the structure of any app should be like:

- You have root level component that serves their purpose. Like: `input box`
- Then you have a composite component, that will consume these root components. Like handling error labels along with input.
- Then you have form Higher Order Components(*HOCs*). These are business components and have context of whats going on. These components should have access to Redux store.

---

#### Example:

Lets create a form with basic info:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Age
- Email

For such form, you need following components:

- Text input component
- Number input component with text prevention/validation logic.

You can use `textInput` for `FirstName`, `lastName` and `email`. So if you directly tie it to store, you are making it dependent to your own redux structure. So these components cannot be used anywhere else.

Hence, best idea is to create dumb components that accept props and do their thing.

---

#### Your usecase.

You have following modules:

- Main
- Chat
- FriendsList
- Friend

In future, you plan to add few more modules:

- AI / Bot chat
- Group Chat

Now the chat window for individual, bot and group chat would be similar but the store structure will be difficult. Especially for Group chat.

So how do you decide, which component should bind to store?

You should create nested component hierarchy for you view and create an HOC for your business modules. This way, your view components are not dependent on store. Your HOC will provide data and thats all it does.

So in your case, you will have following HOCs:

- Direct Chat
- Bot Chat
- Group Chat
- Contacts
- Dashboard

And you can have following view component:

- Chat component: Used for all chats types.
- Contact component: Used for friend list/ contact view
- List component: Used for browser contact, add members view and manage members view.

Comment: Ok , but in my case, Chat and FriendsList are relatively complex components - might fall under the third category.

Comment: @sheff2k1 Please check the update. Hope it answers your query

Comment: I sort of get it. But this of course would only be relevant once (and if..) i extend my app. So you're saying that it makes sense to wrap Chat with a HOC, and render it from Main?

Comment: @sheff2k1 Point is, you should keep your View separate from Store. So you have a view layer and you have data store, and HOCs are the bridge. So essentially, the purpose of an HOC is to pick what to show and give them what they need. View components work on simple principle. *I need following things and I'll work till you supply them. Outside world is oblivious to me.*.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Imho it really depends on the situation:

1) If the Child component consumes data independently, it always taking data from the same branch of global state tree: I'd connect it to Redux.

- A TaskList component which always gets task list from state.tasks
- A CurrentUserDetail component which always gets user info from state.currentUser

2) If the Child component consumes data depending to its parent: I'd take data from parent via props. Or take instructions from parent on how to take data from global state, then connect it to Redux and take corresponding data:

- A Task component which gets task data from its parent TaskList component for each task
- A TaskList component which gets taskListID from its parent, then gets corresponding task list. Eg: taskListID="Martin" -> state.tasks['Martin']

Comment: Well, then it seems to me that i can wire up Chat and FriendsList with Redux, being that they virtually depend only on it, without any "instructions" from Main